# there are some problems with typescript and react-loader

Tags: typescript, react-router, react-loadable

When I use typescript and react-loader, the console reported errors like this

[image]

This is for a new project test. using react-loadable to achieve dynamic loading

```
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';
const Home = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('../home/home'),
  loading: <div></div>,
})
```

what's wrong with this

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
 
    **Loading component**

```
import React from 'react';
import Loadable  from 'react-loadable';

interface LoaderProps extends Loadable.LoadingComponentProps  {

}

const Loader : React.FC<LoaderProps> = (props: LoaderProps) => {

  return (
    <div>Loading...</div
  );
};

export default Loader;
```

**Loadable component**

```
/**
* Asynchronously loads component
*/
import Loadable  from 'react-loadable';
import Loader from 'components/Loader';

export default Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./Home'),// where Home is your component
  loading: Loader,
});
```

Comment: Adding `React.FC<LoadingComponentProps>` worked for me! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';
const Home = Loadable({
    loader: async () => {
        const module = await import('../home/home')
        return module.default // or module.Home if you have named exports
    },
    loading: <div></div>,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to extend **Loadable.LoadingComponentProps**, otherwise it will give type error when you'll import the Laoding Component.

```
interface LoaderProps extends Loadable.LoadingComponentProps  {}

const Loading: FunctionComponent<LoadingProps> = props => {
 //your JSX
}
```